# Custom date range (-1 through +7 days from today)

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to show an 8 day date range that shows one day in the past through 7 days into the future but the relative date range is only before or after in a Tableau workbook.

Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Create the following calculation and mark as "True"

```
[Date] >= TODAY() - 1 and [Date] <= TODAY() + 7
```